# Problem with AudioQueueStart() on iPad

Tags: iphone, audioqueueservices, audioqueue

I am having the following problem with Audio Queue Services, and was hoping it sounded familiar to someone else.

First I execute:

`AudioQueueAddPropertyListener(audioQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning, MyAudioQueueIsRunningCallback, self);`

Then later I execute:

`AudioQueueStart(audioQueue, NULL);`

Both calls return no errors but `MyAudioQueueIsRunningCallback` never gets called. I can even call `AudioQueueGetProperty` to check the property `kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning` and this check confirms that the property is non-zero.

I've obviously left a lot of code about but I think these are the essentials. The strangest part is that the code works fine on the iPad 3.2.2 when compiled for Debug but not Release. It also works fine when compiled for Release on the iPhone 4.0 and iPod 4.0, as well as both simulators in xcode.

If it makes any difference, the code I'm using is derived from [this file](http://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer/blob/master/Classes/AudioStreamer.m).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this was the solutions,

[AudioQueue problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274864/audioqueue-play-audio-when-callback-will-get-hit)

Basically, you must start AudioQueue form the MainThread( perhaps UI Thread )