# AudioQueue, Play Audio When Callback will get hit,

Tags: objective-c, macos, audioqueue

In my application, i will receive buffer from the Socket, and need to play it, App will receive buffer in approx every 50 ms,

The way i am doing is as follows,

1 -- Define the Audio Format, which is as given below,

```
FillOutASBDForLPCM (sRecordFormat,
                    16000,
                    1,
                    16,
                    16,
                    false,
                    false
                    );
```

2 -- Create & Allocate AudioQueue Buffer

3 -- Enqueue Buffer

4 -- Start the Queue,

Now i understanding is that, it should hit automatically Callback as and when it played existing buffer and then ask for the new buffer, but in my case, its not hitting Callback automatically, as and when i am getting buffer , i am calling Callback explicitly , is this correct method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, i was starting AudioQueue from the one intermediate thread and after debugging i came to know, it needs to have Main Application thread. 
This is the reason, callback was not invoking by it self.